# How to write to/ update values in a CSV via a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new to Python and just now learning about the Pandas module so I wouldn't be surprised if I just didn't recognize the answer. I am trying to write a program that writes and updates csv files using pandas (it's a modified point buy calculator for dnd).

This is a method in one of my classes:

```
def update_character_as(name, ability_name, score):
    record = pandas.read_csv(f'{name} scores.csv')
    record.loc[ability_name] = score
```

So far it modifies the ability scores but not inside the actual .csv file. Do I need to open the .csv file and use `.write` or does Pandas have something built in that I am missing?

Comment: Your CSV is on disk. Your dataframe is memory, so they're completely separate. If you want to write your dataframe to disk, see the section in the pandas docementation labeled "IO Tools" (IO = input, output)

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html

Comment: Pandas helps you to work with downloaded data, but if you want to add new information in files you can  use method: to_csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv

Answer (score 0):

Please create CSV file. Here, {name} scores.csv => your_character scores.csv (sample one is below).

to_csv() saves the last data on the same file.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

def update_character_as(name, ability_name, score):
    record = pd.read_csv(f'{name} scores.csv', index_col=0)

    # update the specified ability score. 'Strength' = 16
    record.loc[ability_name] = score

    # save the updated DataFrame back to the CSV file
    record.to_csv(f'{name} scores.csv')

update_character_as("your_character", "Strength", 16)
```

**your_character scores.csv:**

```
Ability,Score
Strength,14
Dexterity,12
Intelligence,10
Wisdom,8
Charisma,18
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your CSV is on disk. Your dataframe is in memory, so they're completely separate. If you want to write your dataframe to disk, see the section in the pandas documentation labeled [IO Tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html) (IO = input, output)

- [comment](/q/77319914/#comment136310357_77319914) by [Paul H](/users/1552748/paul-h), lightly modified

Specifically, you want [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)